Remove last 9 character in alternate lines of file in unix
I need to remove last 9 character from a file starting from Line number 4 and remove only on alternate lines 6,8.. like that to last Line of file

Any question should show reasonable research effort. What have you tried? How did this fail? Where are you stuck? Please respond by [edit]ing the question.

Assuming you want to remove the last nine characters from the 4th, 6th, 8th... lines, not "the last 9 character from the file on those lines" which would not make sense to me, that could be:
sed '3,${n;s/.\{9\}$//;}'

Or:
perl -pe 's/.{9}$// if $. >= 4 && $. % 2 == 0'

(add the -C option if the input contains UTF-8 encoded multibyte characters or -Mopen=locale to decode the file as per the locale's character encoding as with the other solutions).
Or
awk 'NR >= 4 && NR % 2 == 0 {sub(/.{9}$/, "")};1'

Example:
$ printf '%s\n' {01..10}-123456789 | sed '3,${n;s/.\{9\}$//;}'
01-123456789
02-123456789
03-123456789
04-
05-123456789
06-
07-123456789
08-
09-123456789
10-

$ printf '%s\n' {01..10}-123456789 | perl -pe 's/.{9}$// if $. >= 4 && $. % 2 == 0'
01-123456789
02-123456789
03-123456789
04-
05-123456789
06-
07-123456789
08-
09-123456789
10-

$ printf '%s\n' {01..10}-123456789 | awk 'NR >= 4 && NR % 2 == 0 {sub(/.{9}$/, "")};1'
01-123456789
02-123456789
03-123456789
04-
05-123456789
06-
07-123456789
08-
09-123456789
10-


On GNU sed:
sed '4~2s/.\{9\}$//'

From the manpage of Linux sed:

first~step
Match every step'th line starting with line first. For example, ''sed
-n 1~2p'' will print all the odd-numbered lines in the input stream, and the address 2~5 will match every fifth line, starting with the
second. first can be zero; in this case, sed operates as if it were
equal to step. (This is an extension.)

If you want to modify the file itself in-place, add the -i flag to your sed command.

Thanks for your solution.works like a charm. Appreciate it.
